How to configure cache for docker executor in gitlab-runner?
I've configured it for caching by referring to the official documentation, but now I don't know how I can use it in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. How do I go about writing the path to this path?
config.toml
I don't know how I can use it in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. How do I go about writing the path to this path?
.gitlab-ci.yml
